# cannot use the part to traverse the element

Tags: spring, mongodb, updates, criteria, spring-data-mongodb

I have this query:

```
 Query query = new Query();
 query.addCriteria(where("cakes.color.owner._id").is(new ObjectId(person.getId())));

 Update update = new Update();
 update.set("cakes.color.owner", person);

 mongoOperations.updateMulti(query, update, StockEntity.class);
```

And this the structure of the objects that I use:

```
    public class StockEntity {        
            private List<Cake> cakes= new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public class Cake implements Serializable {
            private Color color;
    }

    public class Color implements Serializable {
            private Seller owner;
    }
```

The problem is that I get the error:

```
Write failed with error code 16837 and error message 'cannot use the part (cakes of cakes.color.owner) to traverse the element({cakes:[{cake:{color:{owner:_id:ObjectId('5a0c1bd15efad44437b2e76d')}}}]} )
```

Why do I have this error? any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Because you are trying to update a field inside an array

Comment: I tried to use elemMatch but I have the same error.

Answer (score 2):

There are limitations to the positional operator `$` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/
I assume you use mongo version <= 3.4

Try this out: `update.set("cakes.$.color.owner", person);`

Comment: I thought that this solved the problem, but the thing is that the positional operator `$` for mongo version <= 3.4, always updates the first element automatically.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I mentioned it comes with limitations. So there is no out of the box solution. You could iterate in for each loop if you know the number cakes.